# Analyzing Hisaishi Joe's "The Bygone Days" 2

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

[image]

The song is in D Maj

I can't understand how that B Maj at bar 12 came out

G maj7(IV), A(V) then B maj (VI) ?

How does this work ?

Comment: are you sure this song is in D Maj? not a D major chord to be found.

Answer (score 2):

The song is definitely in D major, it just doesn't resolve to D major chords very often in this excerpt.

**The B chord is a secondary dominant as part of a deceptive resolution** (IV-V-VI). It's kind of like **ii-V-iii-vi-IV...*** in that the deceptive resolution is there, skipping the iii in that circle of fifths example. The B chord normally would be minor, but making it major gives it that color, and also its **tendency to resolve to Em** (though in this case it's G major, but they're both subdominants, so it doesn't matter).

Also worth noting is that the A6 noted there also contains the 9th, so I'd call it A6/9, and it already contains the note B, which sets up the B major chord.

Comment: Great answer! I would just add that it does resolve to DMaj in bar 5.

Comment: @jdjazz Edited it.

Comment: Why is it kind of like ii-V-iii-vi-IV ? I kind of thought that it's a deceptive resolution using the pivot chords of D Maj key's relative minor key ( b ) Gmaj being the "bVIM7" A7 being "bVII7" and B being the "i"but just changed to Maj because even in minor keys they end the part by Maj "I"sometimes

Comment: If you want, you can look at it that way, that's perfectly acceptable. Just be prepared to defend your position that the song is in B minor.